# New column using the column names as the values of the new one?

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble such as here below. See that it uses the character "Y" for the values.

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(a = c('Y', NA, 'Y'), b = c(NA, 'Y', NA))
df

# A tibble: 3 × 2
      a     b
  <chr> <chr>
1     Y  <NA>    
2  <NA>     Y
3     Y  <NA>
```

And I want to create a new column combining the other two (or more) however changing the "Y" to match the name of the columns. In this case "a" and "b". Such as this

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      a     b    c
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     Y  <NA>    a
2  <NA>     Y    b
3     Y  <NA>    a
```

I am pretty confident that there is no more than one "Y" in each row. I don't think I can solve this using `gather` or `mutate`

Comment: Asked many times before: `names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df))]`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
ind <- which(!is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
df$c <- names(df)[ind[,2][order(ind[,1])]]
df$c
#[1] "a" "b" "a"
```